# How can user send malware code via input=file

Tags: javascript, html, file, security

After the file is uploaded via input=file it is converted to b64 standard. But what is the exact path the file is going through and where in javascript code we can catch that uploaded file. And if I don't have any file upload handling functions can user write and execute malware code into file and execute it?

Example: Can I encode **console.log('it worked');** to the **jpg, png, ...** file and execute it when uploading to browser?

Comment: The simple answer is no, it's not possible. The long answer is it sometimes is, but depends on many things. You may want to look at force browsing vulnerabilities, what x-content-type-options does, image processing vulnerabilities (like the one in imagemagick not very long ago) and so on. A full hacking tutorial doesn't fit an answer here unfortunately.